# 3COM switch "Can't find source file" error on tftp put

Tags: tftp, 3com

I am trying to upgrade my 3COM switch firmware. I am following the instructions on these links:

http://alextakacs.blogspot.com/2011/06/upgrading-firmware-on-3com-4500-switch.html
http://mymcp.blogspot.com/2010/02/upgrading-firmware-on-3com-4500-switch.html

However I am getting en error executing the `tftp` command

```
<4500>tftp 192.168.0.41 put flash:/3comoscfg.cfg
```

The error I get is this:

```
File will be transferred in binary mode.
Sending file to remote tftp server. Please wait... 
Can't find source file .
```

And the output of `dir` command:

```
<4500>dir
Directory of unit1>flash:/

   1       -rw-      5195  Feb 04 2007 13:21:21   3comoscfg.def
   2 (*)   -rw-   4228223  Apr 02 2000 00:18:31   s3n03_03_02s168p19.app
   3       -rw-    195022  Apr 02 2000 00:19:06   s3o04_06.btm
   4       -rw-    995524  Apr 02 2000 00:19:40   s3p04_04.web
   5 (*)   -rw-      4815  Apr 02 2000 04:37:25   3comoscfg.cfg
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was on my TFTP server. I changed the following line on my `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` file:

```
server_args = -s /var/tftpboot/
```

to this:

```
server_args = -c -s /var/tftpboot/
```

And the problem is solved.  The missing -c option allows new files to be created on the TFTP server.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify merely

```
tftp 192.168.0.41 put 3comoscfg.cfg
```

It's possible that the command parser is choking on the `:/` or is not expecting an absolute path.  Your command line is otherwise the same as the example given in the documentation I have on a random 3com managed switch, for what it's worth.

You could also try specifying a destination filename as the last argument:

```
tftp 192.168.0.41 put 3comoscfg.cfg someswitch-backup.cfg
```

If that works and the first one doesn't, it seems like a bug, but it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but neither one worked :( Still getting the same error

Comment: Weird.  Try unit1>flash:/3comoscfg.cfg for the source file?  Also, maybe try uploading some other file, just to test...